# PHP regex: Check text rows for duplicate rows

Tags: php, regex

Having lines

```
(01) Some text
(10) Foo Bar
(11) ?
(13) Foo Bar
(13) ?
(20) Something else
```

check 4 rows in a batch. If row 1 and 3 are the same and row 2 and 4 are `(XX) ?`, then replace rows 2-4 with `...` so it results as

```
(01) Some text
(10) Foo Bar
...
(20) Something else
```

---

**Code:**

```
$arr = explode("\n", $t);
if ( count($arr) > 3 )  {
    for ($i=1; $i<count($arr); $i++) { // check 4 rows
        if( ($arr[$i-1] == $arr[$i+1]) // if row 1 and 3 are the same
           && preg_match('/\(\d+\) \?$/', $arr[$i]) // and row 2 is "(XX) ?"
        && preg_match('/\(\d+\) \?$/', $arr[$i+2])  // and row 4 is "(XX) ?"
       ) {
            print "Match!"; //test. later replace rows 2-4 with a row "..."
         }
     }
}
```

This currently gives me an offset error.

Test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/iMO3BW

How could this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **regex** pattern

```
^(\(\d+\)\s+)(.*)[\n\r]\(\d+\)\s+\?[\n\r]\(\d+\)\s+\2[\n\r]\(\d+\)\s+\?[\n\r]
```

with **multiline** and **global** modifiers.

---

See **[this regex test](http://regexr.com?32mr4)**.

Comment: Oh, plain regex! Didn't see that solution coming. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are scanning up to two elements into the future, while iterating to the very last element. You can see that happening here.

```
preg_match('/\(\d+\) \?$/', $arr[$i+2])
```

Change your FOR statement to be the following.

```
for($i=1; $i<count($arr) - 2; $i++)
```